# When onResume is called background goes blank

Tags: android, background, dialog, surfaceview, onresume

I have `Dialog` on transparent activity and it's like a pause menu, so when dialog is shown and I press `Home` button everything works fine but when I reopen it `Dialog` shows, except the background is blank. Game is made  with `canvas` and `SurfaceView` so I can't display  `Dialog` on that screen or can I, because I was trying but I get error every time

So when I press back key `Dialog` shows perfectly:

[image]

But when I click Home button and that long click on Home button to reopen app I get this:

[image]

onResume code:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ourSurfaceView.resume();
    }

public void resume() {
            isRunning = true;
            ourThread = new Thread(this);
            ourThread.start();
        }
```

Activity which shows `Dialog`:

```
public class ShowPopUp extends Activity {

    Dialog myDialog;
    GameSurface ourSurfaceView;
    Button toMenu;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.showpopupmain);

        myDialog = new Dialog(ShowPopUp.this);
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.showpopup);
        myDialog.setTitle("Paused");
        myDialog.setCancelable(true);
        Button button = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.Btn1);
        toMenu = (Button)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.Btn2);
        toMenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                Intent menu = new Intent(
                        "com.example.mygame.Menu");
                startActivityForResult(menu, 5);
            }
        });

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myDialog.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
        });
        myDialog.show();
        myDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                ShowPopUp.this.finish();

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: So you have a `Activity` with a `SurfaceView` over which you pop up the dialog `Activity` and when you dismiss that the background of the `SurfaceView` is blank?  What does the `ourSurfaceView.resume();` look like?

Comment: I posted it under onResume that's the function in other class :)

when I reopen Application Dialog shows, except the background is blank.

Comment: So the background of the Dialog is blank?

Comment: no the transparent activity where dialog is is black color but when i press back goes to normal again

Comment: I'm guessing that is because that activity hasn't been recreated yet.  When the activity stack was set aside to go to the Home screen for example that whole stack is saved.  Then when you go back to it the OS only starts the top activity, which is the one with the transparent background.

Comment: so how can I achieve that background doesn't go blank?

Comment: I edited it hope you can answer it now :)

Comment: You can use an actual dialog instead of an Activity that looks like a dialog.  That way the activity on top of the stack when your app comes back will be the one with the drawing in the background.

Comment: How can I draw Dialog to SurfaceView if I try it I get error

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: I tried adding dialog to my surface view, still i face this issue on resume. Anything you can help with?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Casey's comments:
Could you try to dismiss the dialog inside the activity's onPause() and see if your SurfaceView resumes?
If it does, you can use onResume() to show the dialog again (after resuming the surface).

You should probably have an additional flag in your surface/game loop keeping track of paused/resumed game state (not just drawing state), so you can run the drawing loop (so it's visible) without advancing the actual game.